# Pass QXmlStreamReader Instance to Class

Tags: c++, qt, class, qxmlstreamreader

I am trying to read an XML document using QXmlStreamReader. I am running into issues when I try to pass a pointer to the reader to other classes. I create an instance of the reader in one class. That class reads the XML until it comes to a block defining a new class. I create and instance of the new class and then call a function in that class to continue reading the XML specific for it. For instance:

```
void SF_UnitClass::ReadModes()
{
    Q_ASSERT(XML.isStartElement() && XML.name() == MODES);
    NumModes = XML.attributes().value(COUNT).toInt();            
    while (XML.readNextStartElement())                                          
    {
        if (XML.name() == MODE)                                            
        {                                                                      
            ModeClass* pMode = new ModeClass(this);                          
            ModeList += XML.attributes().value(ID).toString();                
            pMode->ReadXML(&XML);                                              
            {                                                                  
            }
        }
        else                                                                    
        {
            XML.raiseError(QObject::tr("Something other than Mode block encountered in Modes block"));
        }
    }
}

void ModeClass::ReadXML(QXmlStreamReader* pXML)                                 
{                                                                               
    Q_ASSERT(pXML->isStartElement() && pXML->name() == MODE);                   
    while (pXML->readNextStartElement())                                        
    {                                                                           
        int nameIndex = ModeList.indexOf(pXML->name().toString());            
        if(nameIndex != -1)                                                     
        {                                                                       
            switch(nameIndex)                                                   
            {                                                                   
                case 0:                                                         
                {                                                               
    qDebug() << "Mode: Receivers";                                              
                    NumReceivers = pXML->readElementText().toInt();             
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
                case 1:                                                         
                {                                                               
    qDebug() << "Mode: Channels";                                               
                    ReadChannels(pXML);                                         
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
                case 2:                                                         
                {                                                               
    qDebug() << "Mode: Servos";                                                 
                    ReadServos(pXML);                                           
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
            }                                                                   
        }                                                                       
        else                                                                    
        {                                                                       
    qDebug() << "Mode: Error " << name;                                         
            pXML->raiseError(QObject::tr("Unrecognized keyword for Mode"));     
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                           
}                                                                               

void ModeClass::ReadChannels(QXmlStreamReader* pXML)                            
{                                                                               
    Q_ASSERT(pXML->isStartElement() && pXML->name() == CHANNELS);               
    NumChannels = pXML->attributes().value(COUNT).toInt();                      
    while (pXML->readNextStartElement())                                        
    {                                                                           
        if (pXML->name() == CHANNEL)                                            
        {                                                                       
    qDebug() << "Mode: Read Channel";                                           
            ChannelClass* pChannel = new ChannelClass(this);                    
            pChannel->ReadXML(pXML);                                            
        }                                                                       
        else                                                                    
        {                                                                       
            pXML->raiseError(QObject::tr("Something other than Channel block enc
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                           
}                                                                               

void ModeClass::ReadServos(QXmlStreamReader* pXML)                              
{                                                                               
    Q_ASSERT(pXML->isStartElement() && pXML->name() == SERVOS);                 
    NumServos = pXML->attributes().value(COUNT).toInt();                        
    while (pXML->readNextStartElement())                                        
    {                                                                           
        if (pXML->name() == SERVO)                                              
        {                                                                       
    qDebug() << "Mode: Read Servo";                                             
            ServoClass* pServo = new ServoClass(this);                          
            pServo->ReadXML(pXML);                                              
        }                                                                       
        else                                                                    
        {                                                                       
    qDebug() << "Servos: raiseError";                                           
            pXML->raiseError(QObject::tr("Something other than Servo block encou
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                           
    qDebug() << "Mode: Read Servos Exit";                                       
}                                                                               

void ChannelClass::ReadXML(QXmlStreamReader* pXML)                              
{                                                                               
    Q_ASSERT(pXML->isStartElement() && pXML->name() == CHANNEL);                
    ChannelNumber = pXML->attributes().value(ID).toInt();                       
    while (pXML->readNextStartElement())                                        
    {                                                                           
        int nameIndex = ChannelList.indexOf(pXML->name().toString());           
        if(nameIndex != -1)                                                     
        {                                                                       
            switch(nameIndex)                                                   
            {                                                                   
                case 0:                                                         
                {                                                               
                    UserName = pXML->readElementText();                         
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
                case 1:                                                         
                {                                                               
                    EndPointHold = String2Bool(pXML->readElementText());        
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
                case 2:                                                         
                {                                                               
                    ServoPriority = String2Bool(pXML->readElementText());       
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
            }                                                                   
        }                                                                       
        else                                                                    
        {                                                                       
            pXML->raiseError(QObject::tr("Unrecognized keyword for Channel"));  
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                           
}                                                                               

void ServoClass::ReadXML(QXmlStreamReader* pXML)                                
{                                                                               
    Q_ASSERT(pXML->isStartElement() && pXML->name() == SERVO);                  
    ServoNumber = pXML->attributes().value(ID).toInt();                         
    while (pXML->readNextStartElement())                                        
    {                                                                           
        int nameIndex = ServoList.indexOf(pXML->name().toString());             
    qDebug() << "Servo: NameIndex: " << nameIndex;                              

        if(nameIndex != -1)                                                     
        {                                                                       
            switch(nameIndex)                                                   
            {                                                                   
                case 0:                                                         
                {                                                               
                    Offset = pXML->readElementText().toInt();                   
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
                case 1:                                                         
                {                                                               
                    PosFactor = pXML->readElementText().toInt();                
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
                case 2:                                                         
                {                                                               
                    NegFactor = pXML->readElementText().toInt();                
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
                case 3:                                                         
                {                                                               
                    SecServo = pXML->readElementText().toInt();                 
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
                case 4:                                                         
                {                                                               
                    Unit = pXML->readElementText().toInt();                     
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
                case 5:                                                         
                {                                                               
                    Ser1 = pXML->readElementText().toInt();                     
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
                case 6:                                                         
                {                                                               
                    Ser2 = pXML->readElementText().toInt();                     
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
                case 7:                                                         
                {                                                               
                    Ser3 = pXML->readElementText().toInt();                     
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
            }                                                                   
        }                                                                       
        else                                                                    
        {                                                                       
    qDebug() << "Servo: raiseError";                                            
            pXML->raiseError(QObject::tr("Unrecognized keyword for Servo block")
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                           
    qDebug() << "Servo: Exit ";                                                 
}                                                                               

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<SmartFlyUnit version="1.0">
    <UnitName>PowerExpander Eq10E</UnitName>
    <UnitCode>PE-5</UnitCode>
    <UnitID>1</UnitID>
    <MinRev>1.0</MinRev>
    <MaxRev>1.9</MaxRev>
    <Servos>36</Servos>
    <Outputs>32</Outputs>
    <UnitMode>Chan</UnitMode>
    <Modes Count="2">
        <Mode ID="Chan">
            <Receivers>1</Receivers>
            <Channels Count="10">
                <Channel ID="0">
                    <UserName></UserName>
                    <EndPtHold>Off</EndPtHold>
                    <ServoPri>Off</ServoPri>
                </Channel>
                <Channel ID="1">
                    <UserName></UserName>
                    <EndPtHold>Off</EndPtHold>
                    <ServoPri>Off</ServoPri>
                </Channel>
            </Channels>
            <Servos Count="36">
                <Servo ID="0">
                    <Offset>0</Offset>
                    <PosFact>1.0000</PosFact>
                    <NegFact>1.0000</NegFact>
                    <Reverse>Off</Reverse>
                    <SecServo>0xFF</SecServo>
                    <Unit>0xFF</Unit>
                    <Ser1>0xFF</Ser1>
                    <Ser2>0xFF</Ser2>
                    <Ser3>0xFF</Ser3>
                </Servo>
                <Servo ID="1">
                    <Offset>0</Offset>
                    <PosFact>1.0000</PosFact>
                    <NegFact>1.0000</NegFact>
                    <Reverse>Off</Reverse>
                    <SecServo>0xFF</SecServo>
                    <Unit>0xFF</Unit>
                    <Ser1>0xFF</Ser1>
                    <Ser2>0xFF</Ser2>
                    <Ser3>0xFF</Ser3>
                </Servo>
            </Servos>
        </Mode>
    </Modes>
    <MCUs Count="1">
        <MCU ID="0">
            <FileName>/PE-5/PE-5_M0_1_00.sffw</FileName>
        </MCU>
    </MCUs>
    <FPGAs Count="1">
        <FPGA ID="0">
            <Configs Count="2">
                <Config ID="0">
                    <FileName>/PE-5/PE-5_F0C0_1_00.sffw</FileName>
                </Config>
                <Config ID="1">
                    <FileName>/PE-5/PE-5_F0C1_1_00.sffw</FileName>
                </Config>
            </Configs>
        </FPGA>
    </FPGAs>
</SmartFlyUnit>
```

I added the code that the ModeClass uses to recognize a channel and servo block. I also added the code from ChannelClass and ServoClass.  Lastly I added an edited version of my XML file but enough to show the problem.  This XML reads fine into my TreeWidget code (not shown).  What happens when I read it into the code above is that all the channels are read correctly, then it reads the first servo block and returns all the way up to the main ModeClass loop instead of reading the next servo in ModeClass::ReadServos.  I know this is a lot of code but it seemed the only way to show the issue.  Thanks,

Comment: you need to post body of pMode->ReadXML

Comment: OK, added a lot more to the code and the XML I am reading.

Answer (score 0):

Qt docs say:

> Reads until the next start element within the current element. Returns
>   true when a start element was reached. When the end element was
>   reached, or when an error occurred, false is returned.

So when you encounter start element, using `readNextStartElement()` will search inside the element you found

i.e.

```
<xml>
</xml>
<xml>
</xml>
```

What will happen here:

1. `readNextStartElement()` will stop on first `<xml>` node
2. `readNextStartElement()` will return false, as it finds `</xml>`

in a little bit modified example:

```
<xml>
  <child>
  </child>
</xml>
<xml>
</xml>
```

1. `readNextStartElement()` will stop on first `<xml>` node
2. `readNextStartElement()` will stop on `<child>` node
3. `readNextStartElement()` will return false as there is no xml node inside `<child>` node

What should you do, you ask?

after you get to node you're insterest in, and read all info you need you must call `skipCurrentElement()` so `QXmlStreamReader` will go to the end of the current element

So modyfing a little bit first sample:

```
<xml>
</xml>
<xml>
</xml>
```

1. `readNextStartElement()` will stop on first `<xml>` node
2. `skipCurrentElement()` will stop on closing of first `<xml>` node
3. `readNextStartElement()` will stop on second `<xml>` node

Comment: I see what you are saying but I am reading the entire file and should recognize all the nodes.  There is nothing I want to skip.  I am building a data base from the XML.  I posted more code and a short XML file.  A better description of what works and does not was added I hope. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, you don't want to skip anything. Did you try to use debugger to see where exactly your parsing code stops? Setup breakpoint in `SF_UnitClass::ReadModes()` and go step by step

Comment: For some reason I am having trouble with the debugger.  I set a break point and when I get there if I do a step over it gives me an error saying it cannot insert breakpoint -422 and halts debugging.  The debugger must be configured wrong but I don't know how to fix it.  If I just run the program there are no errors it just does not do what I want it to.  That is why I am using debug statements.

Comment: OK, I feel dumb.  This was all working but in my switch I missed a case so the read was getting out of sequence.  I need a default in the switch to warn me that the block has an element that is not in the switch statement and then call skipCurrentElement().  Thanks for your help, your example did help me realize what I was missing.

Comment: Glad I could direct you to the solution instead of giving it out at plate :)